# How to open a door using a phrase with speech recognition and python

Tags: python, google-api, voice-recognition

i'm having some trouble with a code using the google api speech recognition.
That's what i need: The "door" must open when i said the right phrase,but i'm a beginner python coder, so, i don't have enough knowledge about it.

That's my code till now:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def ouvir_microfone():

    microfone = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        microfone.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

        print("Say something: ")
        audio = microfone.listen(source)
        try:
            frase = microfone.recognize_google(audio,language='pt-BR')
            print(frase)
        except sr.UnkownValueError:
            print("Doesn't Undestand")

        return frase

frase = ouvir_microfone()
```

I'm from Brazil, so there's some words that's in my language.

Comment: I think your indentation is not quite accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Setup the script to open the door as described [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Garage-Door-Opener/).

2) Write a function to run the script to open the door:

```
def open_door():
   os.system("/usr/bin/opendoor")
   return
```

3) In recognition script compare with the target phrase and run the script:

```
frase = microfone.recognize_google(audio,language='pt-BR')
if frase == "open door":
      open_door()
```

Thats it